# An SQL query is blocking another though the blocking session is 0

Tags: sql, oracle, concurrency, oracle10g, locks

I am logged in from two applications operating on same table and doing two operations from the two programs, causing background SQL queries to run. And one operation is causing the other to get stuck or run very slowly. I found these two queries to be held together for a very long time.

1. select count(*) from table ....
2. insert into table......

Also, can you please tell about how I can show the locks acquired by the queries in run time or see which queries might be conflicting?

Comment: Showing the conflicting locks is very, very DBMS-specific.  You'll need to specify which DBMS you are using.  The information in the stream of dots for the SELECT might be very relevant to why that takes so long; presumably, there is a WHERE clause which forces a table scan.  The information in the stream of dots for the INSERT statement is also likely to be relevant; it probably isn't a simple VALUES list for a single row.  There are other factors involved; the isolation level might be an issue.  If you're using MySQL, it might well be relevant to know InnoDB vs MyISAM, too.  Etc.

Comment: You should also show us how you found out that the "*blocking session is 0*"

Comment: additionally: select and insert should not *block* each other (at least not in a modern DBMS)

Comment: The application is using oracle 10g db.

Comment: I saw the blocking session 0 by doing select * from v$lock. can you please tell me about how i can see the locks that are being acquired in real time.

Comment: @user1957130 there's more friendly views than looking in v$lock. `dba_blockers` `dba_waiters` `dba_dml_locks` and `dba_ddl_locks` to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have any locking issues, as a select does not request any locks.

What you may be experiencing is that the select has to resort to the before-images, i.e. the values before the insert (assuming the insert and the select use the same table). The before images are stored in rollback segments and accessing them is somewhat costly.

Still it makes little sense to query the number of rows of a table which is in the process of being filled. What would the result tell you? It will be wrong a microsecond later. This suggests, you shoud reconsider the logic behind it all.